# Three dimensional associative array for Json?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

After several attempts, I have to ask for some help to solve this. Below I have some plain JSON:

```
{
    "test": {
        "r1": [{
            "id": 1,
            "status": true
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "status": true
        }],
        "r2": [{
            "id": 1,
            "status": false
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "status": false
        }]
    }
}
```

This works fine with javascript when I'm reading from a simple .txt file, but I want to create this JSON from PHP. I can make a two dimensional associative array, but for this it seems that I need a three dimensional associative array, and I can't solve that! Could someone give me a hint how that would look or alternative solutions?

Comment: By the look of it: `array($your_array)`

Comment: Create it from what input?

Comment: Actually, you will need a four-dimensional array from for that. But if you know how to create a two-dimensional array, this shouldn't be a problem for you - the same rules apply here. Here is an example, how you can read / write to such array: `$arr['test']['r1'][0]['id'] = 1`. Did I understand right what you're asking?

Comment: @charlietfl I want to create a JSON file like this backend and then read then with AJAX and use them as objects in Javascript.

Comment: @PetrR. Thanks for the info how to read/write this array!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an embracing example with your data on how to convert from JSON object (string) to PHP array and vice-versa.
Hope this makes things clear for you.

```
<?php

// Original JSON object string
$jsonstring = '{
    "test":{
        "r1":[{
            "id":1,
            "status":true
        },{
            "id":2,
            "status":true
        }],
        "r2":[{
            "id":1,
            "status":false
        },{
            "id":2,
            "status":false
        }]
    }
}';

// Convert JSON string to PHP array
// This can be used by a PHP script to work on
$phparray = json_decode($jsonstring);
echo '<h3>PHP array converted from JSON string</h3><pre>'; var_dump($phparray); echo '</pre>';

// Convert it back to JSON string to prove it's the same
$jsonstring1 = json_encode($phparray);

// Now we create a PHP array corresponding to original JSON string, manually
$phparray = array (
    "test"=> array (
        "r1" => array(
            array(
                "id"=>1,
                "status"=>true
            ),
            array(
                "id"=>2,
                "status"=>true
            )
        ),
        "r2" => array(
            array(
                "id"=>1,
                "status"=>false
            ),
            array(
                "id"=>2,
                "status"=>false
            )
        )
    )
);

// Convert PHP array to JSON string
// This can be sent to a browser where it can be used by Javascript
$jsonstring2 = json_encode($phparray);

echo '<h3>Original JSON string</h3>' . $jsonstring;
echo '<h3>After conversion to array and back</h3>' . $jsonstring1;
echo '<h3>Converted from PHP array</h3>' . $jsonstring2;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is this a four dimesional array? I get an error in this code ($phparray part) when the script read the .php file? What could be the problem?

Comment: The array corresponds exactly to the JSON string you posted. What error do you get?

Comment: I get this: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Perhaps something wrong with this line in my javascript? var myObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

Comment: Yes, probably. Btw: I added comments to the PHP code.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't figure out way I get this error!? My next step is to change this code so that the arrays can be filled in a dynamic way on the server. Any hints how that can be done?

Comment: Now it's working! I made a typing error! Thanks again!